# Не удается установить компилятор ming windows редактор sublime text 3

Tags: c

При автоматической установке компилятора для С (ming windows), он выдает ошибку

```
mingw-get: *** WARNING *** http//prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-min...: opened with unexpected status: code = 403
mingw-get: *** WARNING *** please report this to the mingw-get maintainer
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http//prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-min...: download failed
mingw-get: *** WARNING *** http//prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-min...: opened with unexpected status: code = 403
mingw-get: *** WARNING *** please report this to the mingw-get maintainer
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http//prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-min...: download failed
mingw-get: *** WARNING *** http//prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-min...: opened with unexpected status: code = 403
mingw-get: *** WARNING *** please report this to the mingw-get maintainer
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http//prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-min...: download failed
mingw-get: *** WARNING *** http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-setup-0.6...: opened with unexpected status: code = 403
mingw-get: *** WARNING *** please report this to the mingw-get maintainer
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http//prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-setup-0.6...: download failed
mingw-get: *** WARNING *** http//prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-setup-0.6...: opened with unexpected status: code = 403
mingw-get: *** WARNING *** please report this to the mingw-get maintainer
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http//prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-setup-0.6...: download failed
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-gui.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-lic.tar.xz"
```

При попытке ручной установки он в любом случае перебрасывает на "sourceforge.net" который выдает ошибку "The sourceforge.net website is temporarily in static offline mode".

Большая проблема в том что видео-уроки 2014 года и возможно многое изменилось с того времени. Да , я очень долго и нудно искал как исправить эту проблему, но даже тут ссылки находятся на sourceforge.net который не открывает ссылку на тему а выдает ошибку. У меня сейчас это засело в душе и голове и мне правда хочется научиться, но тут вот так случилось. Прошу помощи людей которые в этом понимают,не знаю можно ли кидать ссылки ( точнее я прочитал в правилах но не уверен), поэтому кину:D

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCYT19xs8mE&list=PLG9dLrY9JZ...

https://sourceforge.net/home.html

http://www.mingw.org/

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему, на этом же сайте сбоку нашел проект https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/ ,установил его и все работает!!